# How to stream videos over local network to TV from PC

Tags: video, media

I have quite a bit of hardware already (A Wii U, an Xbox 360, a Chromecast, a Raspberry Pi etc) but I still can't find a good way to watch the videos saved on my Ubuntu computer, on my TV downstairs. Is this possible? Do I need to buy something else to play them? I thought the Chromecast was going to be the answer but I can't find any working software.

Comment: I believe Google is still working on adding the ability to cast the desktop to Chrome. I would instead try connecting the Raspberry Pi to the TV, using `sshfs` to have the folders in your laptop accessible to the Raspberry Pi through SSH, and then playing the video in Pi.

Comment: @saiarcot895 could you add this as an answer so I can follow your steps and see if they work for me?

Comment: I second the Raspberry Pi solution with sshfs. For a nice media player interface for your Raspberry, take a look at [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/).

Comment: @Jos this looks like the exact solution I was looking for. I think the HDMI out is broken on my pi atm so I'm going to order a new one I think, unless there's something better/cheaper that you (or anyone) can recommend.

Comment: @captainjamie: I added the `sshfs` version as an answer below.

Comment: No, HDMI should work really well on the Pi. Notice also the XBMC apps that turn your smartphone into a remote control, and the tons of plugins.

Comment: @Jos Oh no, it is working now. Just a broken HDMI cable apparently. Wow, I wish I'd have asked this sooner, this stuff is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there isn't any support for casting the desktop to Chromecast (yet), you could instead try playing the video files on the Raspberry Pi itself. This could be achieved by using `sshfs`, which displays the contents of a folder on your computer on the Raspberry Pi by using SSH.

1. Make sure that you have `openssh-client` and `sshfs` installed on the Raspberry Pi, and `openssh-server` installed on your computer. The following steps will be on the Raspberry Pi only.
2. Run `sudo usermod -aG fuse pi`, where `pi` is the username on your Raspberry Pi, and log in and out of your account for the changes to take effect.
3. Create a folder that will display the files in your computer. (For example, `mkdir computerVideos`).
4. Run `sshfs captainjamie@192.168.1.101:/home/captainjamie/Videos computerVideos`, where `captainjamie` is the username on your computer, `192.168.1.101` is the local IP address of your computer, `/home/captainjamie/Videos` is the folder on your computer containing the videos, and `computerVideos` is the folder you created in the previous step.
5. The files in your computer will display in the `computerVideos` folder. Run any videos you want.

Note that this could be extended to any other files as well.

As noted by @Jos above in the comments, you can use [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) to get a nice media player interface with support for plugins.

Comment: I can get ssh to work but not sshfs. It says: `failed to open /dev/fuse` or if I run with sudo: `device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`

Comment: I've sort of worked around it. I changed some permissions and rebooted and now if I run `sudo -i` in the terminal I can run the command and it all works. Sort of. Still need to be root though, can't seem to get on without that

Comment: Strange. Did you try `sudo modprobe fuse`?

Comment: You also shouldn't have to be root to do this, and being root will mess up access through public-key authentication (if you were using this method).

Comment: Right, I just needed to run `sudo usermod -aG fuse pi` (where `pi` is the username on my raspberry pi) and also `exec su -l $USER`. This has fixed everything. (Perhaps add that to your answer)

Comment: Added a slight variation to my answer.